# Ninject: Abstract Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject-2

Do I need to do something different in an abstract class to get dependency injection working with Ninject?

I have a base controller with the following code:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IAccountRepository AccountRepository
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My module looks like this:

```
public class WebDependencyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAccountRepository>().To<AccountRepository>();
    }
}
```

And this is my `Global.asax`:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    Kernel.Load(new WebDependencyModule());
}

protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    return new StandardKernel();
}
```

It works when I decorate the `IAccountRepository` property with the `[Inject]` attribute.

Comment: Edited answer a bit - hope the overall thing is clear now - feel free to follow up in comments if this doesnt make sense. BTW be sure to download the Ninject source - it's the single best place on the planet for answers about Ninject. The tests are a pretty good set of answers .

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea. Going to check out the source code for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do.

It looks like you want to do Property Injection. If so, you have to stick on the attribute.

Ninject doesnt randomly go sticking things in properties.

Even if it could, you wonldnt want it to from the point of view of trying to understand what depends on what (I've weaned myself completely off PI).

If you want to do constructor injection, the concrete Controller will need to ask for one and pass it down to 'BaseController'.

Ninject will walk through to `Object` and inject Attributed properties, but doesnt treat `abstract` classes in any special manner.

Either that or I'm missing something.

Comment: this kinda makes sense to me, as you do not prefer property injection, do you have some sample code? It seems to me you would be passing in the IKernal somewhere, this part I dont fully understand, could you explain please?

Comment: @Haroon: Cant think of any good examples. Have you looked at the [ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Table-of-Contents)? I'm saying you just use constructor injection everywhere. The absence of property injection as a quick way for a base class to get something injected can only be resolved by a) dropping to Service Location (bad) b) making derived constructors demand it on your behalf. Anything where the base class requires the Kernel is no better than service location - at least Propety Injection gives you a level of indirection.

Comment: thats what I am thinking, I dont like the fact i have to pass in the kernal/container and get the ctor to resolve the dependency. Passing in way too much info to that class for my liking. The only problem with the Property Injection is you are tying yourself to Ninject... I seen one example where I can use typeof<myAttribute> that way I am not referencing ninject, only my attribute... either way it all seems very hacky to me especially since I am using an IOC container...

Comment: Cant really do Property Injection without some degree of coupling to container though - either by convention, by attribute or by hardwiring a e.g. `Bind<T>....WithProperty( "name", ... )` But yes, as agreed, PI is to be avoided for more than one reason!